# Consolidated Data, except under certain conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following results(temp table):

```
Product  Side(buy/sell)  TotalQuantity  AverageWeightedPrice  Cost
Prod1    1               100            120                   12,000
Prod1    2               -50            130                   -6,500
Prod2
Prod2
```

So on and so forth for multiple products.

I consolidated it to (with a groupby):

```
Product  Side(buy/sell)  TotalQuantity  AverageWeightedPrice  Cost
Prod1    1               50             110                   5,500
Prod2
```

I want the consolidated results, unless it is certain conditions:

1. When Side 1 and 2 have the same Quantity.  Consolidated quantity would be 0 and I would not be able to calculate the AverageWeightedPrice anymore.
2. When consolidated quantity = 0, the other condition is when TotalQuantity and Cost are of inversed values, ie, when Quantity is positive and Cost is Negative (and when Quantity+ and Cost-)

If it is the certain conditions, I would want to return the UNcosolidated data.

I am having trouble excluding between consolidated and unconsolidated data at the same time.

Comment: I got the suggestion that since you can't do an if/when statements with a group by, I can do a 'having' statement with the groupby and then join the tables later.  I'm going to look into it now but still welcome suggestions.

Comment: Can you add the query you used?

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that SQL is really good for.

It is totally possible to produce this result with pure sql but the solution is very complex and you should not do it if you have any other option for it since sql does not provide any optimization over complex tasks like this and the syntax can be hard to master. Maintaining the query could also prove to be hard task in the future.

In cases like this you should use sql only to fetch the data and then format (consolidate) it using the whichever programming language or application that is executing the query.

Comment: I was thinking of doing a having statements after the consolidation.  Something along the lines of:

.. having TotalQuantity not equal to 0 
and not having the inverse values

I will have a new table of consolidated by product, then join in the unconsolidated query where product not in consolidated query.